# Define same build properties for the same image in multiple services in docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the services `robot1` and `robot2`, and both of them use the same image, but I want to define the context and Dockerfile for that image so it use them when doing `docker compose build`. Now I have it like:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  robot1:
    image: mycompany/remote_test
    build:
      context: ./ctx
      dockerfile: robots.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./commands:/commands:ro
    command: /commands/robot1

  robot2:
    image: mycompany/remote_test
    build:
      context: ./ctx
      dockerfile: robots.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./commands:/commands:ro
    command: /commands/robot2
```

As you see, I must define the same build content in both services, I'd like to know if it's possible to define if outside the service properties, something like:

```
images:
  mycompany/remote_test:
    build:
      context: ./ctx
      dockerfile: robots.Dockerfile
```

And then don't include it inside the services items.

Comment: Can you rename the Dockerfile to just `Dockerfile`, and then use the short form `build: ./ctx`?  You may also be able to get away without specifying the `image:` name.